# Is it possible to change the _default_jwt_payload_handler(identity) by code?

Tags: flask, identity, flask-jwt

I'm having problems using Flask-JWT in my application, I am using the authenticate and identity like this:

```
def authenticate(username, password):
  session = db.Session()
  user = session.query(db.Operators).filter_by(username= username).first()
  if user and bcrypt.check_password_hash(user.password, password):
    return user

def identity(payload):
  user_id = payload['identity']
  session = db.Session()
  return session.query(db.Operators).filter_by(idOperator= user_id)
```

But I get an error because I do not have an id field in my db table because I have an idOperator

How can I solve this problem? The _default_jwt_payload_handler(identity) function goes to seek for an Id field, how can I change this automatic id field to an IdOperator without changing the init.py of flask-jwt?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `jwt_payload_handler` decorator to specify your own payload handler.

For example, mimicing the default behavior but instead using `idOperator` could look like this:

```
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

@jwt.jwt_payload_handler
def make_payload(identity):
    iat = datetime.utcnow()
    exp = iat + current_app.config.get('JWT_EXPIRATION_DELTA')
    nbf = iat + current_app.config.get('JWT_NOT_BEFORE_DELTA')
    identity = getattr(identity, 'idOperator') or identity['idOperator']
    return {'exp': exp, 'iat': iat, 'nbf': nbf, 'identity': identity}
```

Which uses:

```
from datetime import datetime
from flask import current_app
```

Here is [the documentations](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-JWT/#flask_jwt.JWT.jwt_payload_handler) specification.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to consider flask-jwt-extended instead. Flask-JWT has been abandoned for years now, whereas flask-jwt-extended is still actively maintained and much easier to customize: https://flask-jwt-extended.readthedocs.io/en/latest/basic_usage.html